# Quitting the app when goes to the background while the contact activity is open

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-contacts

In our Android application I implemented the contact selection by using Intent action *ACTION_PICK* on the *ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI*. This method works fine (mostly), but unfortunately I have no control over the incoming events activity.

The app have to log out and quit when it is enforced into the background. At the moment it is implemented by making use of the activity event: *onStop()* for the main activity, but obviously the app won't receive that event if the contacts activity from the system is open.

I have tried to subclass the contact activity somehow, but I am afraid it cannot be managed.

I tried to use different activity start flags, but couldn't find any relevant flag for this situation (not to mention that flags are not working with *startActivityForResult()* method).

I tried to hook into different broadcasted events, but there are way too many possibilities that ends up pushing the app to the background.

I have found some tricks for polling the application on the top, but that would require GET_TASKS permission and generally it would be a major hack anyway. I would rather not go there.

So, to sum up my question:

**Is there any way to detect that the application is enforced into the background while the contact activity is open?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, my colleague found the answer:

Add the following properties to the main activity:

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
```

And after the user pressed the home button while the contact selection was open and relaunched the app a new event will be triggered on the main activity:

```
public void onNewIntent(Intent newIntent)
```

The cancel result code is still coming back similarly like when the user pressed the back button on the contact selection activity, but in that case this specific event won't be triggered.
This way I can differentiate between the situations when the user closed down the contact activity and when the system closed it down.

Answer (score 0):

What you do is wait for a result, when the contact is returned the contact application will be creating a new intent with the data and then in your application you should be using something like onActivityResult (I cant remember the actual method sorry)

Look on Android Developers website under resources, in basic or advanced training there is some info about communicating with other applications

---

Edit

```
import android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email;

private static final int CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT = 1001;
private boolean chooseContact = false;
private boolean returned = false;

public void doLaunchContactPicker(View view) {
    Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT);
    chooseContact = true;
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT:
            // handle contact results
            break;
        }

    } else {
        // gracefully handle failure
        Log.w(DEBUG_TAG, "Warning: activity result not ok");
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    if(contactChoose && !returned){
            finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am afraid you misunderstood my problem. I know how to get back the contact, that is fine. What I am looking for: I must quit the app entirely when it goes into the background.
If the contact activity is open and I press the home button (for example) then when I start the app again it still goes back to the contact activity. I have to prevent that.

Comment: Maybe you can have some boolean value that is set to true when you try to get the contact and if it doesn't receive the result then in onStart you can check if it has it or not and whether the boolean is true and then you could finish the application if the result isnt there but the boolean is. Do you see where Im getting at?

Comment: Also there probably is a way to get the intent used to open the application, either the one that launches it or the result.

Comment: Thank you for the hints. I was not able to manage to find out if anything happened in the meanwhile when the contact selection activity is open. When I press the home button, start some apps then start our application again it continues exactly where it left: I can either cancel the activity or select a contact.

Also I wasn't able to find the intent that can be captured for starting the app. In theory it should be "android.intent.action.MAIN" in category "ndroid.intent.category.LAUNCHER", but I wasn't able to receive those actions with the Intent filter.

Comment: I can give you an upvote, but what you suggested is not working. So I am still looking for the solution for this problem...

Comment: No problem. Whats happening now? Except for what you mentioned before?

Comment: There is no difference if you pressed the home button or you didn't while the device contact is open. When you relaunch the app it returns to the device contact selection page and if you dismiss it (by pressing the back button) then you will receive the same result code like you wouldn't press the home button but simply dismiss the contact selection.

Comment: Look at the edit, what should happen is that if the activity receives a result it will continue but if it doesn't receive anything it will finish

Comment: I don't want to quit the app because it didn't receive a selected contact. I must quit only if the user pressed the home button while the contact selection was on the screen.

Comment: Ahh well that clears things up, Im not sure if that is possible but there could be something, Ill have a think about it and get back to you.

Comment: Okay, no worries. Right now I am trying to find some possible flag for the activity that can be specified. I already found that FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY closes the contact selection when the user presses the Home button and returns to the app afterwards. Unfortunately in the activity result there is no difference: the cancel result is coming back, so I cannot tell whether the user pressed the back button or the system closed it down.

Comment: Hmm, I dont think there is any possible solution for this sorry.

Comment: Finally, we have found the solution. Thanks for trying.